# <li> <th> text-align inconsistency

Tags: css, html, cross-browser

In IE, Edge, and Safari, a `<th>` descendant of a `<li>` is center-justified.

In Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, it's left-justified.

According to [**W3C Rendering**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) recommendations (italics mine):

> User agents are expected to have a rule in their user agent stylesheet
>   that matches **th** elements that have a parent node whose computed value
>   for the 'text-align' property is its initial value, *whose declaration
>   block consists of just a single declaration that sets the 'text-align'
>   property to the value 'center'.*

The italicized section states that a `<th>` element should be centered if its parent's `text-align` property hasn't been changed.

That's not the case for `<th>` descendants of `<li>` in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.  Am I correct in assuming that they are ignoring W3C recommendations?

(The problem is easily overcome by using `th {text-align: center;}`, so I don't need a solution.)

#### Edit

I've received a couple of good explanations for the behavior, but the answers are unsatisfactory – through no fault of the posters.

I think the intent of the W3C is that `<th>` elements should be centered *unless* they include or inherit a different *explicit* `text-align` style.  It doesn't make sense that `<th>` elements should be left-justified due to a convoluted cascading inheritance of implicit styles.

It seems to hinge on what W3C means by "its initial value" in the quote.  The "initial value" of a `<li>`'s `text-align` property is `match-parent`, which is apparently different from `text-align: initial`.

Hopefully the W3C will clarify this in the future.  In the meantime, `th {text-align: center;}` solves the problem.

---

**Example:**

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>This is a Lorem Ipsum<br>test</th>
        <th>Another header
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABCDEFG HIJKLMNOP QRSTUV WXYZ
        <td>More
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not ignoring W3C. From the quote in your question,

> a parent node whose computed value for the 'text-align' property is its initial value

But that's not the case. The initial value for `text-align` is `start`, which computes to `start`. But `<li>` elements are styled with `text-align: match-parent`, which computes to `left` since the `<ol>` has `direction: ltr`. Even though `start` behaves like `left` because the `<li>` also has `direction: ltr`, they are different values. That's why the `th` is not centered.

Note both `start` and `match-parent` are recent additions. Possibly the `th` becomes centered on browsers which don't support them yet.

If you use `li { text-align: initial; }` then th `th` is centered.

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
li {
  text-align: initial;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>This is a Lorem Ipsum<br>test</th>
        <th>Another header
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABCDEFG HIJKLMNOP QRSTUV WXYZ
        <td>More
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: So does that mean "parent node" really means "ancestor node" in W3C's recommendation?

Comment: @RickHitchcock The `li` has `text-align: left` instead of `initial`, and the `table`, `tbody` and `tr` inherit that. The parent of the `th` is the `tr`.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  But don't `div` elements default to `text-align: left`?  Their `th` descendants aren't left-aligned.

Comment: No, the default is `text-align: start`. `start` behaves like `left` with `direction: ltr`, but it's a different value.

Comment: So does that mean that IE, Edge, and Safari are wrong?  Or does it mean that the W3C recommendation is ambiguous?

Comment: @RickHitchcock Maybe they don't support `start` or `match-parent`, or maybe they don't style `<li>` with `text-align: match-parent`.

Comment: I thought `initial` was used to restore a default property, which may have been overwritten by CSS.  Why would `text-align: initial` for `li` elements be different from their default of `text-align: match-parent`?

Comment: Because if you use `text-align: initial`, the specified and computed  values will be `start`. If you use `text-align: match-parent`, the specified value will be `match-parent` and the computed value may be `left`. Note that Edge seems to check the cascaded value instead of the computed one, hilariously this means that `text-align: initial` prevents the centering.

Answer (score 5):

your issue is that `li` is by default `text-align: match-parent` (at least on Firefox), which mean the `li` are [`text-align:left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) (if direction is `ltr` otherwise is `text-align:right`)  so if you change `li` to `text-align:initial` the `th` will work as you expect

> **match-parent**
>
> Similar to inherit, but the values start and end are calculated according the parent's direction and are replaced by the
>   adequate left or right value.

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
li {
  text-align: initial
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>This is a Lorem Ipsum
          <br>test</th>
        <th>Another header
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABCDEFG HIJKLMNOP QRSTUV WXYZ
          <td>More
      </tr>
    </table>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I thought `match-parent` had to do with the direction (left/right), not with centering(?)

Comment: exactly it does, the value starts at left (`text-align:left)` if `ltr` or starts at right if `rtl`

Comment: I thought `initial` was used to restore a default property, which may have been overwritten by CSS.  Why would `text-align: initial` for `li` elements be different from their default of `text-align: match-parent`?

Comment: I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oggf7au0/1/) so you can understand the differences

Comment: Thanks, I see the difference, but I guess my interpretation of `initial` was wrong.  See my edit.

Comment: Well `initial` just sets the property to its default value.

Comment: So why isn't its default value its default value, which would be `match-parent`?

Comment: See Oriol's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763220/li-th-text-align-inconsistency/41763372#comment70720742_41763358) he explains it ;)

Comment: Note that `initial` keyword is not supported in Internet Explorer 11 and earlier versions.

Comment: @RickHitchcock just curious on which factor did you have to choose the answer as accepted

Comment: it was really a toss up.  Oriol simply provided a few extra details.

Comment: @RickHitchcock No problem ;) just curiosity !